# Meaning of the phrasal verb "pack in" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/nutritious-breakfast).

> Get ready to **pack in** the protein, healthy fats, and fiber.

Does it mean to include?

Comment: There are two definitions of [pack in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pack-sth-in) with almost opposite meanings. In this context, I believe they are closer to the second meaning of "to manage to include a lot of things in a short time". They are trying to say you need to focus on those nutritional items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pack in a lot of [fiber, etc.]

means: to add those items to your diet (here, your breakfast) or the food you eat/make.

**What Is a Good, Nutritious Breakfast? Get ready to pack in the protein, healthy fats, and fiber**

Taken from the OP's link.

It is not the best English.

And for especially badly written English, it could mean: eat a lot of fiber etc.

Comment: Is that definition sourced from somewhere?

Comment: Definitions aren't sourced. Supplies are sourced from a place or company.

Comment: Not everything is in a dictionary.  Especially when used in a slangy way. Here is the full title. **What Is a Good, Nutritious Breakfast? Get ready to pack in the protein, healthy fats, and fiber**. So, it means to add those items to your breakfast, as I stated generically in my first statement in my answer.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that this is user-generated definition and it is not being taken from an authoritative source.

Comment: Yes, and it funny how neither of those you found work. Not all slangy use is in dictionaries. That's why native speakers have a role to play here.

Comment: @urnonav I feel Lambie's expression *"means: ... "* is the most suitable *"definition"* for the context. Sometimes phrases are used figuratively - and their dictionary definitions don't make sense on paper.

Comment: Dictionary definitions of both "pack" and "pack in" are fairly appropriate in this case, so I am not sure we need to wage any war on dictionaries today.

Answer (score 2):

To pack things in somewhere is to put in as much (or as many) of things as you can. You can pack a lot of clothes in a suitcase if you push them hard. To pack protein, healthy fats, and fiber (or fibre) into yourself means to eat a lot of foods containing these things.

> pack verb (FILL)   [ T ] to fill a space, or to crowd people or things
>   together, esp. in large numbers:

[Pack](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pack)

Comment: Yes, the idea of as much as you can is good.